# Generate a random vector multiple times until a condition is complete

Tags: r, random, vector

I have a vector x=(1,2,3,4,...20) and I want to generate vectors with 5 elements from this vector(elements can be repeated), until there are shown all the elements of the first vector at least once. And then I have to represent the data with a histogram. Any idea how can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: May be use `?sample`

Comment: A simple while loop?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with sample, but I cannot set the condition that will stop the while loop

Comment: I provided the answer below with the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a sample of five elements doing this with replacement (you can set that to false if you don't want replacement sampling):

```
x <- seq(1:20)
shown <- rep(0, 20)
while (!all(shown > 0)) {
  s <- sample(x, 5, replace = TRUE)
  shown[s] <- shown[s] + 1
}
hist(shown)
```

Comment: I modified the code and I got a few histograms for every loop. Is there a way of combining the results in one histogram. I need the distribution of each variable in the random vector. Here is the code:

_
x <- seq(1:20)
vec<-c()
 shown <- rep(FALSE, 20)
while (sum(shown) != 20) {
     n<-sample(x, 5, replace = TRUE)
     sample(x, 5, replace = TRUE)
     hist(n,c(0:20))
     shown[sample(x, 5, replace = TRUE)] <- TRUE
}_

Comment: But this doesn't save the samples. OP indicated they want to produce a histogram.

Comment: @user3949008 look at the comment above

Comment: I edited slightly to save results and plot histogram.

Answer (score 3):

A while loop seems a good way to go here. This solution uses a matrix to capture your samples. Each sample is one row. This makes it easier to do other operations per sample, if you so desire.

```
set.seed(123)  

base_v <- 1:20

#empty matrix to put samples in
mydat <- matrix(nrow=0,ncol=5)

while(!all(base_v %in% mydat)){
  mydat <- rbind(mydat, sample(base_v,size=5,replace=T))
}

#then making the histogram is trivial
hist(mydat)
```

Comment: I believe your code is fine, but every loop must capture how many times each number is shown, and in the end present all the data in the histogram, where one number will be shown only once. This is the condition that stops the loop

Comment: Did you test it? I forgot to set breaks in the histogram, but if you look at  `table(mydat)` you see that there are numbers with only one sample.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
x <- 1:20
s <- integer(0)
while (! all(x %in% s)) {
  s <- c(s, sample(x, 5, TRUE))
}
```

Vector `s` will contain all values drawn from `x`. I trust you will be able to make histogram from it on your own.

Line-by-line explanation:

- `x <- 1:20` - initialize vector `x` with numbers 1..20
- `s <- integer(0)` - initialize empty vector `s` that will store all the results
- `x %in% s` - for every element in `x`, check if it appears anywhere in `s` and return boolean (logical) value
- `all(…)` - return TRUE if all elements in argument vector are `TRUE`; return FALSE otherwise (if at least one is **not** TRUE)
- `!` - logical negation
- `while` - loop that will repeat body as long as condition is evaluated to TRUE
- to sum up: as long as at least one element from `x` is not in `s`, execute code in loop body
- `sample(x, 5, TRUE)` - draw five elements from vector `x`, allow repetitions
- `s <- c(s, sample(x, 5, TRUE))` - concatenate drawn values to vector `s` and assign this new vector back to `s`

Comment: That's exactly what I need